# What can this rebus solve? How can this rebus be solved?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, english, language

This is my first rebus, constructive suggestions are welcome. Enjoy!
[image]
Mistake: the diagonal of the green circle on the right should be from the top right to the bottom left instead of from the top left to the bottom right. Sorry!

Top **full** view of the blue-white thing in green background:

> something similar to this
> [image]

Hint:

1:

> the only piece of knowledge needed from one of the tags is given in the rebus

2:

> [english](/questions/tagged/english) is here, but things are basic here ■ ‿ ■

3: OK, gonna ruin the [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) tag:

> it should be [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics)

4: top left

> A name I call myself

5: top middle

> $CN(terra)$

Comment: If it doesn't give away the answer, what's in the second picture? Can't really tell, is it a bar of soap?

Comment: @J.Dionisio sorry but which do you mean by second pic? thanks!

Comment: the one with something blue with what appears to be grass in the background

Comment: @J.Dionisio see edit ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I liked this puzzle a lot, however, why do you start it with 'sol', when you actually mean 'mi'? 'Mi' would be a line lower.

Comment: really? oh, that's my fault :( i meant mi... sorry im terrible at music, even its such a simple mistake... Thanks for pointing that out @ThomasBlue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Final Answer**

We know the final solution is:

> The **Quadratic Formula**

Like so:

> [image: Quadratic Formula]

First two pictures

> As hinted, the musical note (a 'G' in the treble clef) relates to "a name I call myself" which itself relates to the third note in the Solfège system, 'mi' (see *Do-Re-Mi* from *The Sound of Music*). The second image is part of a "frisbee", which would give us the 'is b' we need as the first term in the formula.
>
>  
> So with "mi" + (n) + "is" (sounds like us) + "b", we get "minus b" or $-b$

Third picture

> Credit to @Matthew Barber, who discovered that "The Chinese for Saturn is 土星, the first part of which looks a bit like the ± sign.", which gives us our $±$ symbol

Fourth picture

> The rotation symbol gives us "rot", and the inner symbol looks like a zero, which gives us a second 'O' to make "root", or $√$
>
> The first icon inside the circle is a 'B' chord for a guitar, but "squared", which gives us the $b^2$
>
> The second icon inside the circle is 4 air-conditioners (credit to @Hugh for spotting that). Commonly abbreviated to 'AC', this would give us $4ac$
>
> Together with the minus symbol in the picture, we get $√b^2 - 4ac$, also known as the 'discriminant'

Bottom picture

> This is 2 A's, but because they are "under" all the other pictures, we could say that the top row is "over $2a$", giving us the bottom of the formula

Comment: There is a "minus" followed by four air conditioners in the top-right image, that's "minus four ACs" or $-4ac$.

Comment: @Hugh nice observation! :D

Comment: ...and I'll bet that the other *thing* in the green symbol is the "b squared" part (dot in a square --> b squared?).

Comment: Updated the answer, possibly a chord diagram for guitar?

Comment: In addition, the fact that the frisbee is "cut off" intrigues me. This is enforced by the fact that Omega Krypton uses the words "full view" to describe the frisbee in the spoiler.

Comment: The partial frisbee could be rot13[vforr = vf o]?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton should be pretty close now?

Comment: nice job, +1+check! decoding the last  bit for you rot13[ahf sbe zvahf pbzrf sebz gur vf va sevforr, fvzvyne fbhaq; ebbg pbzrf sebz ebgngr flzoby (ebg) + gur mreb va ebg guhf (eb0g) --> ebbg]

Comment: Neat puzzle @OmegaKrypton! :) looking forward to your next rebus!

Answer (score 4):

One part of the puzzle, which I don't think has been mentioned yet:

> The Chinese for Saturn is 土星, the first part of which looks a bit like the ± sign.

Comment: correct, nice job!